# Django - Better way to set checked checkboxes on a search form based on GET parameters

Tags: django, django-forms

I've done a good bit of searching, but it doesn't seem like this particular brand of form creation is addressed anywhere.

I'm creating a search page that queries the database for the set of all elements which have attributes at or above a given threshold. Right now I have a simple form that has 5 attributes, which have 5 thresholds each, each with their own checkbox i.e.

```
attrib_1 X threshold 1 X threshold 2 X threshold 3 X threshold 4 X threshold 5
attrib_2 X threshold 1 X threshold 2 X threshold 3 X threshold 4 X threshold 5  
... etc ...
```

The HTML looks something like this:

```
  <div class= "form-inline">
    <label>Attribute 1</label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="attrib 1" value="1"> Very Negative
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="attribt 1" value="2"> Negative
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="attrib 1" value="3"> Nonfactor
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="attrib 1" value="4"> Positive
    </label>      
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="attrib 1" value="5"> Very Positive
    </label>
  </div>
```

I then search the database using the information in the GET parameters. When I display the search results, what's an elegant way to make sure the checkboxes reflect the search query? I expect that the user will check some boxes, look at the results, then check some more to refine the search and I don't want them to have to recheck all the boxes each time they submit a search.

I've considered a few way to do this. I could use if/else statements for each checkbox and fill in the checked attribute appropriately. This would work, but seems inelegant, not very DRY, and would result in a very complex template. Alternatively, in the view I could create a data structure (dict of lists or list of tuples, probably dict of lists), which would have either 'checked' or the empty string for each checkbox. This would result in a cleaner template, but I suspect there's a more properly Django/Pythonic way to do this. I also considered a custom form, but that seemed like trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

So, what's an elegant way to make sure that check boxes on a search form are properly checked based on GET parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are POSTing back to the page with a refresh, instead of AJAX. In which case...

I will assume (as per Django standards) that you've made all these checkboxes a part of a Django form. In that case, you can pass the forms a series of arguments (I would suggest a dictionary) that contains the initial value for all of your checkboxes.

```
class SearchQuery(forms.form)

#Adding an init will allow us to pass arguments to this form In
# This case, a single dictionary argument named 'context'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        checkbox_context = kwargs.pop('context')
        super(SearchQuery,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #Now, instead of doing a bunch of if statements, we can say that
        # our dictionary passed a series of True and False keys that will
        # tell us how our checkboxes should be, in their initial state
        self.fields['checkbox_one'].initial = context['box1']

    checkbox_one = forms.BooleanField()
```

So, let's say we passed `context = {'box1':True}` , then our checkbox would be rendered with an initial value of 'True' or 'Checked'

Comment: I'm new to Django and didn't realize that it's Django standard for all forms to be Django forms. Is this the case? It seemed because the forms were pretty non-standard (just checkboxes, each with a group label) that Django's forms might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: Maybe not "The Standard", but they are an incredibly powerful tool, and it seems silly to write all that HTML when you can have Django do it all for you.